# Dojo ValidationTextbox error tooltip remains on page after Dialog is closed with ESC key

Tags: dojo

I am using **Dojo 1.5, theme Claro.** 
I have a dojo dialog that contains a dojo form, a ValidationTextbox and a submit button.
If the textbox has any kind of error, a tooltip showing a message is displayed next to it.
Now, if the error tooltip is displayed, when I press the ESC key the dialog is closed, but the tooltip remains on page.

Here is the code I'm using for addNewUser.html dialog:

```
<form id="formAddUser" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
    <input  type="text" id="txtUserName" style="width: 200px"
            dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
            required="true"
            regExp="[a-zA-Z0-9 \._-]{3,15}"
            invalidMessage="Error message"
            missingMessage="User Name is required."
            trim="true"></input>
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="dijit.byId('dlgAddUser').hide();">Cancel</div>
</form>
```

Here is the code I'm using to open the dialog:

```
function ShowAddUserDialog()
{
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

    var dlg = dijit.byId("dlgAddUser");
    if (dlg == null)
        dlg = new dijit.Dialog({
            id : "dlgAddUser",
            autofocus: false
        });

    dlg.connect(dlg, "onHide", function(){ 
            dlg.destroyRecursive();
        });

    dlg.set("href", "addNewUser.html");
    dlg.set("style", "width: 370px;");
    dlg.set("title", "Add New User");
    dlg.connect(dlg, "onLoad", function(){ 
        dijit.byId("txtUserName").focus();
    });

    dlg.show();
}
```

Any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the tooltip disappears after the focus has been moved to another node, i.e. fired on  the `blur` event. In you case, I think it's because the `blur` event is not fired, since you used the ESC key to close the dialog.

To solve this, you can manually call `displayMessage` of the `dijit.form.ValidationTextBox` to hide the tooltip.

In you code

```
 dlg.connect(dlg, "onHide", function(){ 
        dijit.byId('txtUserName').displayMessage(''); //Add this line to hide the tooltip
        dlg.destroyRecursive();
 });
```